# Manage form data on click of asp.net back button (other than handling though Session or Viewstate)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a form on search page having textboxes, dropdowns, checkboxes. After selection of Search Criteria and clicking on Search button search results displays on another page. I am using a asp button on search result page to go back to search page and I want to retain the form data (textboxes, selection of dropdowns/checkboxes etc. which I have made earlier for search). I have implemented it through Session and Viewstate so I want to know some other way to manage this.

Many Thanks for you replies,
Harish Bhatt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already described the situation above here I was trying to maintain the Form data of search page on click of Back button from search result page, details page and other pages. To maintain this I used the Class `SearchCriteria`. Below is the sample code for Class

```
public class SearchCriteria
{
    private string _strName;
    private string _strCode;

    public string strName
    {
        set { _strName = value; }
        get { return _strName; }
    }

    public string strCode
    {
        set { _strCode = value; }
        get { return _strCode; }
    }
}
```

I have assigned all Search Criteria to this class and kept that in Session so that I can access this anywhere.

```
SearchCriteria objSearch = new SearchCriteria();
objSearch.strName =  txtFirstName.Text;
objSearch.strCode = txtCode.Text ;

if (Session["SearchCriteria"] != null)
{
   Session.Remove("SearchCriteria");
   Session["SearchCriteria"] = objSearch;
}
else
{
   Session["SearchCriteria"] = objSearch;
}
```

One Click of `Back` button from search result, details and other pages I am redirecting to Search Page with the `QueryString` PostBack=1

```
protected void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?PostBack=1", false);
}
```

And on the `Page_Load` of Search page I checked for the 'QueryString' PostBack and based on the QueryString, I have assigned the Search Criteria to the Controls from Session.

```
if (Request.QueryString["PostBack"] != null)
{
    SearchCriteria objSearch = new SearchCriteria();
    if (Session["SearchCriteria"] != null)
    {
         objSearch = (SearchCriteria)Session["SearchCriteria"];
         txtFirstName.Text = objSearch.strName;
        txtCode.Text = objSearch.strCode;
    }
}
```

I don't know what is recommended for different situations but like to know. Please share your ideas.

Many Thanks to Ashish Bahu, his answer helped me a lot on this.

I was looking for any other good way to do this without using Session or Viewstate but didn't found anything and finally end up with the above solution, If someone is having any other good solution for this please share. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are many things You can do.

```
1.Cross Page Scripting
```

One of the problems faced by us in ASP.NET 1.x versions is the inability to transfer data between pages easily. Since ASP.NET 1.x pages postback to the same page by default, and you cannot do a post to another page (unless you remove the runat="server" and other messy things), accessing the controls in the previous page becomes very difficult unlike classic ASP where you have a action tag to specify the new page and you can use the Request.Form to access the previous page values.

There is a more effective way of accessing the Controls in the previous page in ASP.NET 2.0. Its using the PreviousPage property of the Page.

Say we have a page Default.aspx with a Textbox "Text1" and a Button "Button1".

We can access the controls in Default.aspx from another page by the following steps:-

A. Setting the PostBackUrl property of the Button to the New Page, as follows:-

```
<asp:Button ID="button1" Runat=server Text="submit" PostBackUrl="~/NewPage.aspx" />
```

B. Then, in the NewPage.aspx.cs, you can access the TextBox control on Default.aspx as follows:-

```
  public void page_load()
    {
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("Text1");
    Response.Write(tb.Text);}
    }
```

Note that a new TextBox tb is declared and typecasted using the PreviousPage and FindControl of the ID of the Control in the Previous Page.  However, to retain the value across postbacks within the new page, its better to assign the text to a TextBox or Label in the NewPage.aspx such that its value is not lost across postbacks.  The reason behind is that, the PreviousPage becomes invalid once you postback in the same page.

```
2.Sessions
```

You can refer the below link for help
    http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/sessions/
example 
Session["Value"]="Any Data";
You can access it in any page

```
3.Cookies
```

Creating a Cookie Object

```
HttpCookie _userInfoCookies = new HttpCookie("UserInfo");
```

Setting values inside it

```
_userInfoCookies["UserName"] = "Abhijit";
_userInfoCookies["UserColor"] = "Red";
_userInfoCookies["Expire"] = "5 Days";
```

//Adding cookies to current web response

```
Response.Cookies.Add(_userInfoCookies);
```

Comment: Thanks Ashish for your detailed answer. Can you please tell me know what is recommended out of these 4 methods.

Comment: Use Viewstate and avoid the use of sessions. The viewstate does not store in the server, instead it is stored in the client side and maintains it state between server and client. The session on other hand stored on the server and creates the extra load on server if application is large.

Comment: I guess it depends on your requirement. if you only want to be displayed in next page, i guess Cross Page scripting works fine because it does not has any extra overhead.

If you want the data to be accessible in whole website then you should for  sessions or cookies.


I guess Cross Page scripting should work fine for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query string that holds the IDs of the selected items in textbox, dropdown, check box, etc., like this:

```
Search.aspx?textId=3&dropdownId=7
```

You would also need to pass these values to your results page, so they can be passed back to the search page when you want to get back.

```
Results.aspx?textId=3&dropdownId=7
```

Note: This alternative becomes unwieldy as the number of parameters increases, but it is a viable alternative to `Session` cache.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Karl and my apology I forget to mention that I have implemented this too but this fails when I comes back after visiting two or three more pages. If let me know if you have any idea how we can handle this. Many Thanks.

Comment: You have to keep passing the query strings along with every request then to mitigate this risk, another reason this solution is not ideal.

Comment: Thanks Karl Will try this out and will get back you if I need some more information or it fails somewhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend storing clientstate information in a the database -- they are occasionally useful that way! You can define the corresponding rows and columns to represent the state info you need to track or just put all of your state info into a persisted stream (using json, xml etc.) as long as your don't to to search or perform db operations on the streamed values. Putting this in a database makes it easy to migrate to a web farm, or add failover, etc. The clientstate database database does not have to be the same database as the rest of your application for more scalability. If you are using sessionstate, you can also configurate asp.net to keep session state in a database to accomplish the same thing. Personally I store the heavily used clientstates in custom table, and use the general streamed method for lower volume clientstate info.

The trick is to use the sessionid as the key (or the sessionid + XKEY) where XKEY is needed if you need to store multiple copies of state info in the same table. e.g., on a storefront app XKEY might represent page # or suchlike. I also use this to generate a unique XKEY and pass the XKEY in the uri query parameterlist -- you only have to persist XKEY from page to page, not a long list of parameters.